# How to extract key and value as separate columns from a JSON string column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a DataFrame with columns `col1` and `col2` where `col2` can contain a JSON string or a plain string. If it contains a parsable JSON string I need to extract the keys and values to separate columns as lists else it should return an empty list as a third and fourth row.

I am using pyspark to achieve this. Any help is appreciated here.

**Source DataFrame:**

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| col1|       col2                                   |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
|a    |{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}                 |
|b    |{"key5":"val5", "key6":"val6", "key7":"val7"} |
|c    |"just a string"                               |
|d    | null                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

**Desired DataFrame:**

```
+-----+----------------+----------------+
| col1|   keys         |   values       |
+-----+----------------+---------------+
|a    |[key1,key2]     |[val1,val2]     |
|b    |[key5,key6,key7]|[val5,val6,val7]|
|c    |[]              |[]              |
|d    |[]              |[]              |
+-----+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: This is a very specific case and you will need a tailor-made solution. You should make a UDF that takes String and returns2  lists. It should 1) validate JSON 2) if invalid, return two empty lists 3) if valid return list of keys and values (json could be parsed as python `dict` using `json` module and you can do `.keys()` and `.values()` on it)

Comment: Thanks @ Samir Vyas for your answer.It was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys in jsonpath is `$[*~]`, values is `$[*]`. But that doesn't look like it's supported by `get_json_object`.

So we need user defined functions:

```
def json_keys(s):
     import json
     try:
         data = json.loads(s)
         return list(data.keys())
     except:
         return None
spark.udf.register("json_keys", json_keys)

def json_values(s):
     import json
     try:
         data = json.loads(s)
         return list(data.values())
     except:
         return None
spark.udf.register("json_values", json_values)

df.selectExpr("col1", "json_keys(col2) keys", "json_values(col2) values").collect()
```

Which yields:

```
+----+------------+------------+
|col1|        keys|      values|
+----+------------+------------+
|   a|[key1, key2]|[val1, val2]|
|   b|[key5, key6]|[val7, val6]|
|   c|        null|        null|
|   d|        null|        null|
+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Mathieu Longtin for your answer.The solution is helpful,interestingly I also tried the similar approach but was curious if there's a way to solve this without udf and from your comments it appears may be not.I have accepted your answer but I don't have the reputation to up vote the answer

Comment: I have to say I like @blackbishop's answer better. I didn't know about `from_json`.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I don't really like the other answers which suggest using UDF for this.

For Spark 2.2+, you should use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) function to convert json strings into map type then use [`map_keys`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys) function to gets the keys and [`map_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_values) function to get values:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, map_keys, map_values

df1 = df.withColumn('col2', from_json('col2', 'map<string,string>')) \
        .withColumn('keys', map_keys('col2')) \
        .withColumn('values', map_values('col2')) \
        .select('col1', 'keys', 'values') 

#+----+------------------+------------------+
#|col1|keys              |values            |
#+----+------------------+------------------+
#|a   |[key1, key2]      |[val1, val2]      |
#|b   |[key5, key6, key7]|[val5, val6, val7]|
#|c   |null              |null              |
#|d   |null              |null              |
#+----+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use pyspark function explode from sql module:
From Docs:

*pyspark.sql.functions.explode(col)[source]
Returns a new row for each element in the given array or map. Uses the default column name col for elements in the array and key and value for elements in the map unless specified otherwise.*

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
eDF = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, intlist=[1,2,3], mapfield={"a": "b"})])
eDF.select(explode(eDF.intlist).alias("anInt")).collect()
[Row(anInt=1), Row(anInt=2), Row(anInt=3)]

eDF.select(explode(eDF.mapfield).alias("key", "value")).show()
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|    b|
+---+-----+
```